# React i18Next variables in elements no longer work

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

Since the update to React18 I have the problem with i18next that I can no longer write variables in labels or similar.

The following code worked without problems in React17:

```tsx
<Field>
 <label className={"p-error"}>{errors.username?.message}</label>
</Field>
```

But since react18 I get the following error message:

```
TS2322: Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactI18NextChild | Iterable<ReactI18NextChild>'.   Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>>' is not assignable to type 'ReactI18NextChild | Iterable<ReactI18NextChild>'.     Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<DeepRequired<any>>>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, props
```

I have read that in the current version it should be possible to set the `allowObjectInHTMLChildren` option somewhere so that this error no longer happens, however I am not clear where I can set this option. I tried it in the init method of i18next, but there this option is not available.

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/issues/1817#issuecomment-1189335968

Comment: Did you found a fix for this?

Comment: @Northstar In case it is still relevant, yes, you just need to exten the react-i18next type inside a typescript definition file, this is the code used to get this working: https://gist.github.com/manuelpoelzl/8a7239b65b3844c38c96061b18e8a431

Comment: @user17145524 github link is broken