# Use react-i18next Trans component with parameters and typescript

Tags: typescript, react-i18next

I have this component:

```
<Trans t={t} i18nKey="welcome_user" name={user.name}>
    Welcome <strong>{{name}}</strong>
</Trans>
```

and this translation, for example in italian:

```
{
  "welcome_user": "Benvenuto <1>{{name}}</1>"
}
```

The page is rendered correctly (translated, with the user name, in strong), however typescript complains:

```
TS2322: Type '{ name: void; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactI18NextChild | Iterable<ReactI18NextChild>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | Iterable<ReactI18NextChild>'.
    53 |                     <Trans t={t} i18nKey="welcome_user" name={user.name}>
  > 54 |                         Welcome <strong>{{name}}</strong>
       |                                           ^^^^
    55 |         
                             </Trans>
```

What is the correct way to do this with typescript?

Comment: What version of React are you using? Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73090818/react-i18next-variables-in-elements-no-longer-work ?

Comment: React v18, indeed that is the issue you linked. Solved as in https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/1483#issuecomment-1213024223 even though I don’t know if that is the correct way to do that

Answer (score 0):

From [i18n-parser docs](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-parser?tab=readme-ov-file#supporting-helper-functions-in-trans-tags), we can use a custom function which casts the object into string. Its a well defined hack, when you will import your function from some `@/app/i18n`:

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => (
  <Trans>
    Visit
    <Link to='/user/john'>{castAsString({ name: props.name })}'s profile</Link>
    {/* Equivalent to, but resolves typechecker errors with */}
    <Link to='/user/john'>{{ name: props.name }}'s profile</Link>
  </Trans>
)

function castAsString(record: Record<string, unknown>): string {
  return record as unknown as string
}
```